# What index i should make?

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have created a table **data_test** contain two fields **issue_date , calling_number**
I have added partition for this table. **PARTITION BY RANGE ("ISSUE_DATE")** flow daily.
and created a local index on **calling_number**.
Which index should I make in order to use the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM data_test WHERE issue_date >'01-sep-2014' 
AND calling_number = '902000001'.
```

Now it is selecting too slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to maintain uniqueness and create index only for performance reasons then create non unique local index by column calling_number. Partition key column not need to be indexed as local index will be partitioned by this column anyway and when you specify condition by issue_date only appropriate index partitions will be scanned.

```
 create index data_test_idx on data_test(calling_number) local;
```

Comment: thank for your reply, I created index that you refer above before i asked this problem and it only fast when i select on daily. Ex:SELECT * FROM data_test WHERE issue_date ='01-sep-2014' 
AND calling_number = '902000001' because it is local index so it's still slow when SELECT * FROM data_test WHERE issue_date >'01-sep-2014' 
AND calling_number = '902000001'.

Comment: What do you mean slowly? You have inexact comparisons clause (more) which could return many values, i.e. scan many partitions. It is not because of "incorrect" index but because of your condition/data. P.S.: I would recommend to use date literals instead of string literals if issue_date column type is DATE

Comment: Btw, can you please provide explain plans for your query and for SELECT * FROM data_test WHERE issue_date > date'2014-09-01' AND calling_number = '902000001'; ?

Comment: Result 23 records. Not too much. 
Plan
3 SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS
Cost: 0  Bytes: 4,652,813  Cardinality: 38,453  
Partition #: 0    
 2 TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID data_test
 Cost: 0  Bytes: 4,652,813  Cardinality: 38,453  
 Partition #: 1  Partition access computed by row location 
  1 INDEX RANGE SCAN data_test_UK [Analyzed]
  Cost: 0  Bytes: 0  Cardinality: 2,769  
  Partition #: 0
I have a constrain UNIQUE (issue_date, calling_number)
I intend change partition daily to monthly.
Thank you